# PrepareForSegue for dynamic Array in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, uitableview

I want to make programmatically segue from `TableView`. Content of the cells is dynamic - the're changing, so I can't wrap segue to the number of row (ex. `indexPath.row = 1`). My array is like that:

```
myArray = [value1, value2, value3]
```

But value1 can be today "A", but tomorrow will be "B". So today value1 should redirect to AController, but tomorrow - to BController. Name of the value is of course displayed in the `TableView`.

I suppose `prepareForSegue` should be based on name of the value (ex. if name of the value is 'A', then...). But I don't know the method.

Any help will be appreciated :)

To be more clear - how my array is generated:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
var countDays = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fmt.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pl_PL")

    var date = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

    while countDays.count < 7 {
       let weekDay = cal.component(.Weekday, fromDate: date)
       if weekDay != 0 {
            countDays.append(fmt.stringFromDate(date))
       }
       date = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    }
    print(countDays)
```

Comment: The weekday comparison is completely useless because the weekday index is never 0.

Comment: Why useless? It works for me.

Comment: By definition `weekDay` is never zero, so the check always succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use "didselectRowAtIndex" delegate method of tableview. You will get the current index path of cell which user has selected/clicked.Use this index path to retrieve corresponding object in your array.Next check the value in retrieved object "A" or "B" using if/else, depending on this you can launch your "AController" or "Controller".Use prepare for segue to launch you specific controller.

Note : all this logic should be done in you "didselectRowAtIndex" method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I should use didselectRowAtIndex, but the question for me is, how to ask for specific string in row. Should it be something like: "if cell.textLabel!.text == "ABC" {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segueABC", sender:self) ??

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer you should retrieve the object from your table view array using "index path.row". This object is the same object which you used to populate your clicked/selected cell. Now this object should have the "string " which you are talking about. if(<your retrieved object from array>.<objectType(A or B)> == "A"){performSegue("SegueA")}

Comment: Can you please advice me method that you would use?

Comment: Array *tableViewArray = @{A,B,C} ; selectedObject = tableViewArray.objectAtIndex[indexpath.row]; This is how you can retrieve the selected object

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this with code:

> let cell: UITableViewCell =
>   tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
>           let str: String = cell.textLabel!.text!
>
> ```
>     if str.containsString("A") {
>         performSegueWithIdentifier("AMonday", sender:self)
>     }
> ```

Easy, but finding this was painful ;)